# Подключение к БД phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, localhost

Не получается подключиться к базе данных, пробовал простейший запрос с выведением ошибки (приведен ниже) ничего не вышло. При попытке входа с корректными данными и некорректными ошибка не появляется. Вообще никаких действий не происходит

```
<html>
<head>

<title> Мой сайт</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234");
$db = mysql_select_db("my_bd");

if(!$connection || !$db)
{
    mysql_error();
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

С html я знаком чуть больше суток, возможно ошибся в какой-то совершенно очевидной и элементарной вещи.
Файл открываю через localhost.
Wamosercer 3.1.0
MySQL бд phpMyadmin

Может быть кто-то таки поймет в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: вы вероятно хотели вывести текст ошибки, но `mysql_error()` для ее получения вызвали а вот `echo` забыли сделать

Comment: mysql_error должен вывести ошибку "по умолчанию". Но и echo в if цикле я тоже попробовал вставлять. Эффекта никакого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_select_db("my_bd",$db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8_unicode_ci' COLLATE 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT='utf8'");
?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает. Но появилась проблема. При открытии файла в localhost - латиница выгляит так - ������� ���������. Может быть подскажете как исправить и это?

Comment: @PavelBobrov попробуйте поставить [<meta charset="utf-8">](http://htmlbook.ru/html/meta/charset).

Comment: Если открыть файл не на localhost - все символы отображаются. Скорее всего это настройки сервера. Какую кодировку нужно выбирать ан сервере и какое сравнение?

Comment: @PavelBobrov: попробуйте кодировку сервера: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) - Сопоставление кодировки соединения: utf8_mb4_unicode_ci (Юникод многоязычный регистронезависимый)

Answer (score 2):

Это расширение устарело с версии **PHP 5.5.0**, и удалено в версии **7.0.0**. Вместо него используйте *mysqli* или *PDO*